# Display Login/Logout on the client when using IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, openid, identityserver4

I have 2 clients and 1 IdentityServer4 applications.

I am using implicit flow and I would like to show login/logout label on my ASP .Net Core client page (top-right corner). What is the best way to do this ?

Is there any sample MVC Core application that is showing us how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check to see if a user is authenticated in your razor like so:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // html for logout button
}
else
{
    // html for login button
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I can logout ? The C# code on the client ?

Comment: Raha you can do the following in your controller:

call the controller with lets say /Logout

// GET: /Logout
        [HttpGet("/Logout")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }

Comment: Thanks, Scott.

Is it possible to log out from Client and also at the same time on the IdentityManager Server, I think if I do what you mentioned it will only log me out from client, How about Identity Server ?